# JavaScript for loop math.sqrt()

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that displays the numbers 1 through 25 squared.

I am completely stuck.

```
function square(){
var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(2);
var square = squareRoot;

for (square = 0; square < 25; counter++){


}

console.log(squareRoot);
```

Comment: share us what you have tried....

Comment: `for (i=1; i<26; i++) { document.write(Math.sqrt(i) ) }` ?

Comment: function square(){
    var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(2);
    var square = squareRoot;

    for (square = 0; square < 25; counter++){


    }

//console.log(squareRoot);

}

Comment: Are you stuck on how to write a loop or how to square a number? There are a ton of examples of both on the web.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code there.

Comment: Some effort to write some code and including that code in the question is required.  And, if you're stuck on something, then please be very specific on what you're stuck on.  "Please write my homework problem" is not appropriate here.

Comment: @adeneo—the OP wants *pow*, not *sqrt*…

Comment: i put the code in the question

Comment: If you want the numbers 1 to 25 **squared** then you should be calculating the square using [*Math.pow*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-math.pow) or just multiplying it by itself, not the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Squared:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/n24vyexx/

```
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
  console.log(i * i);
}
```

OR:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/0g0rqe4p/

```
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
  console.log(Math.pow(i, 2));
}
```

Square root:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/4uep39ev/

```
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
  console.log(Math.sqrt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is a simpler and more straightforward solution, you might want to be able to quickly lookup computed results later.

In this case you can store your results in an object.

```
// first initialize an object for the results to be stored for later use
var results = {};

// define our computation
function squared(x) {
    return x * x;
}

// loop from 1 to 25 inclusive
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; ++i) {
    results[i] = squared(i); // compute and store the result
    console.log(i, 'squared is:', results[i]); // print out the result
}
```

This approach lets you get a fast lookup of the results later on without having them compute again.

```
// you can get existing values
console.log(results[7]); // should print out the result 49

// you can also compute and add the results to your results object
results[100] = squared(100); // stores the result 10000 as value for the key 100
```